# Поиск символов одной строки в другой

Tags: python, поиск, строки

Помогите решить.

Даны две строки a и b. Написать программу, которая выводит на экран строку a, без тех символов, которых нет в b. 
Пример: a=“Hello”, b=“lH”, результат: a=“Hll”.

Answer (score 2):

```
filter(lambda x: x in b, a)
```

Comment: Как-то слишком умно.

Comment: так и должно быть.

Comment: Ну вообще у меня не пашет))

Comment: Что не пашет?

    >>> a='Hello'

    >>> b='lH'

    >>> filter(lambda x: x in b, a)

    'Hll'

Comment: Выводит: <filter object at 0x00BE87B0>

Comment: Можно это регулярными выражениями сделать?

Comment: > Выводит: <filter object at 0x00BE87B0>

занчит у вас  python3.x, нужно так

    ''.join(list(filter(lambda x: x in b, a)))

Comment: @LinnTroll, Спасибо

Comment: `filter(functools.partial(operator.__contains__, set(b)), a)`

Простите, не удержался. (: